# Взаимодействие с Sharepoint 2013 (SOAP)

Tags: sharepoint

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо получить доступ к (например) спискам Sharepoint (далее SP) (на нем организованно информационное пространство).
Как я понял SP может отдавать в виде xml списки и др. для этого необходимо "собрать" http запрос вот примерно такой:

```
POST /_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 94.79.55.82
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/Login"
Connection: Close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Login xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </Login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Конкретно этот вариант опять же как я понял для авторизации, а SP в случае успеха ответит тоже XML и отдаст ID сессии, который я должен буду в "куках" вместе с каждым запросом к SP отправлять. Вот делаю я так и не получается ... ответ сервера выглядит так:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: e8233b9c-feb3-20fe-3a7b-8a3a286b5dd2
request-id: e8233b9c-feb3-20fe-3a7b-8a3a286b5dd2
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 2
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4420
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 08:50:49 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 16

401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

То есть там даже не происходит никакой проверки присланных мною данных, и чего-то не хватает ему ... Может я не верно понимаю назначение этого сервиса или где-то ошибся. Спасибо заранее за советы и комментарии.

Comment: а как выглядят ваши запросы?

Comment: @triplustri у вас же NTLM авторизация, а вы пытаетесь пройти form-based аутентификацию. без указания ЯП сложно что-то советовать... Почему вы, кстати, решили формировать запросы и xml самостоятельно, а не воспользоваться соответствующим soap-клиентом?

Comment: Сейчас немного разобрался с NTLM, то есть клиент получая такие заголовки:"WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate", "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM" - должен от пользователя потребовать ввод логина и пароля. Думал может если SP слать вот такие soap сообщения он будет авторизовывать не NTLM, а уже на основании присланного мною, но получается ее (NTLM авторизацию) не обойти. Что касается использования soap-клиента, не использовал потому-что нет потребности в нем, вроде и так "склеил" сообщения, но сейчас думаю может с ним (soap-клиентом)ошибиться труднее. ЯП - вообще тестю на PHP, но цель - интеграция с 1С.

Comment: @dthpth я их привел первый блок кода это запрос, второй - ответ

Comment: в 1с есть же WSОпределения и проч для работы с soap ([тут пример есть](http://infostart.ru/public/182550/)), вам достаточно будет просто вызвать метод, по загруженной сигнатуре и все, генерить пакеты не надо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте подключиться через SoapUI сюда:

```
http://your-sharepoint/your-site-collection/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl
```

Изучите доступные методы и пишите свой soap клиент.

Answer (score 0):

В Sharepoint есть 2 механизма доступа к содержимому это серверный код SSOM и клиентский код CSOM. [Ссылка на документацию microsoft][1]

[1]: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest нет необходимости придумывать свой soap client